# How to change a sites URL

Tags: installation

**CiviCRM 5.14.0**

I've read several explanations of how to change a sites URL but I am not having luck. I have made the changes in my apache2 sites-available conf file and restarted apache2. I have also changed the base in civicrm.settings.php. Now the new URL just goes to the Apache default page.

Some things I have read say I have to clear the CiviCRM cache but I can't do that if I cannot access the site.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What CMS are you using? Wordpress / Drupal / etc

Comment: If you're getting the Apache default page, the CiviCRM cache (and CiviCRM in general) isn't the issue here.  This may be a better question for Stack Overflow, since it's an Apache configuration issue.

Comment: Wordpress 5.2.2. I have changed the server name in the Apache2 .conf file in sites-available to specify the new domain.

Comment: It was not an Apache configuration. It was a combination of Wordpress and CiviCRM settings that needed to be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a system admin question rather CiviCRM specific. I personally don't have very good experience in doing this but when there is URL changes

1. Make sure your new domain is pointing to correct server IP
2. Update the url in apache or nginx conf.
3. Update .htaccess file in your site directory if its using any base url.
4. Update the base url in wp-settings.php or drupal's settings.php file.
5. Update the base url in civicrm.settings.php file
6. Clear drupal and civicrm cache
7. If using wordpress you may need to update in database

Query:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'http://new_domain.org' WHERE option_name IN ('siteurl', 'home');
```

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Perfect! It was Item 7 that did the trick. I changed the domain name in the database as all is good. Thank you very much. I had been struggling for a long time with this.